# Cfloop in sql statement?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, concatenation, cfloop

I was wondering if it's possible to loop inside sql statement. In my case I had two years that I created for testing purpose. Now I would like to create years dynamically because I can have more than two records. Here is my code that I used for testing purpose:

```
Select sum(case when quarter = '2015' then 1 else 0 end) as year2015,
       sum(case when quarter = '2016' then 1 else 0 end) as year2016
From testTable
```

Now I have cfloop that gives me years as 2015, 2016, 2017, ...
So I tried something like this but that did not work:

```
Select 
      <cfloop from="#startYear#" to="#endYear#" step="1" index="i">
            sum(case when quarter = i then 1 else 0 end) as CONCAT('year',i)
      </cfloop>
From testTable
```

Error message:

> [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near
>   'year'.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, if anyone can help please let me know.

Comment: try this `sum(case when quarter = '#i#' then 1 else 0 end) as year#i#`. You'll also need a comma after all but the last one to be valid SQL. Also I think you may just be able to do `select count(quarter) as total, quarter from testTable group by quarter` depending on what output you are expecting.

Comment: So what and how I should handle comma on the end? If I have only one year I will not need comma, if I have 2 and more I need then?

Comment: Isn't think something for a PIVOT or UNPIVOT?

Comment: I don't know that this query should be done in code. I agree with both John and James: this can essentially be reached much easier through the database itself. Plus the above query will select _ALL_ rows in the database and won't limit them to the startyear and endyear. And "quarter = 2015" doesn't really have much meaning. I'm not sure what the intent is here. Can you use SQLFiddle or something of the like to give us a basic database schema and what you're expecting the query to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remember that your resulting SQL string has to be valid. CF variables need to be passed in in your case statement.

```
<cfquery name="foo" datasource="xxx">
    SELECT  1 AS placeholder
            <cfloop from="#startyear#" to="#endyear#" index="i">
                -- prepend comma before each statement. Also, variable i must be passed in since it exists as a CF variable, not a SQL variable.
                ,SUM(CASE WHEN quarter = <cfqueryparam value="#i#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year#i#
            </cfloop>
    FROM    testTable
</cfquery>
```

NOTE: this assumes the datatype of quarter is an integer. Change `cfsqltype` attribute as needed.

You could also use a `PIVOT` function to build out your columns.

Comment: I don't think this will return more than 1 on any year. It's running an aggregate on 1 or 0 without any sort of grouping, so the sum() isn't really doing anything. And I don't think the queryparam is really needed here, since the loop is the one generating i.